# Add in Start and End date using PHP

Tags: php, date

I would like to know how to add in new start and end date using PHP. this is my current coding:

```
$startdate = date_create(); echo date_format($startdate, 'Y-m-d'); 

$enddate = date_create(); echo date_format($enddate, 'Y-m-d'); 

$actualdate= strtotime('+1 Week', $enddate);
```

The end result will always be the current date and not the one that I've insert in. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Pretty Unclear. What you actually needed over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
echo $startdate = date('Y-m-d'); // current date
echo $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' + 1 week')); // date 1 week
```

**O/P**

```
2015-11-04
2015-11-11
```

Start date manually -

```
    echo $startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2015-10-04'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this code right now. However I would like to know what if my start date will be the date and I manually key in? One simple example will be booking of hotel room. There will be start and end date that customer will manually type/choose from. The code that I've posted will only show the current date which is not the result that I wanted. It will be great if you can help me solve this issue! Thank you!!(:

Answer (score 0):

To add `one week in` date use

```
$enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime class from PHP(>= 5.2.0).
Here is an example how to add 1 week of current date:

```
$startdate = new \DateTime('now');
$startdate->modify('+1 week');
$enddate = $startdate->format('Y-m-d');

echo $enddate;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php